# React - Ant Design Drawer

Tags: reactjs, antd

I got this error when opening a drawer in ant design v4.10 I also downgrade to my previous version 4.6.x still the error exists.

```
React does not recognize the `scrollLocker` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `scrolllocker` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element
```

Comment: You should show use the React components you've written so we can see where the error is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ant Design version `4.10.1` has fixed this issue. https://github.com/react-component/util/issues/183